# Mishnayos Chazarah Sefer

Tags: halacha

I'm learning Mishnayos now and I'd like to get a sefer of chazarah of mishnayos. Can anyone help me find a sefer for mishnayos chazarah?

Comment: Aren't mishnayos by definition a chazara sefer already?

Comment: Maybe , but I'd like a chazarah on the chazarah you chop

Comment: What would such a sefer contain? There are list of "simanim" to remember the mishnayot (Mishna Sdura has one at the end) with a typical masechet summarised as a page. Is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a sefer that has [chazara questions](https://dafyomireview.com/article.php?docid=386&seriesid=6)  on the whole mishnayos, and its free.